# Selecionar apenas UM checkbox com vanila javascript e bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, html, html5, twitter-bootstrap, front-end

Eu tenho o seguite código que gera o formulário printada na imagem...

```
<div class="form-check form-group" id="areaTermosCondicoes">
     <input type="checkbox" id="accept-term" class="form-check-input">
     <label for="accept-term" class="form-check-label">Li e concordo com os <a href="#">Termos de uso</a></label>
     <div class="invalid-feedback">
          <span class="alert-message"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="valid-feedback">
          <span class="alert-message"></span>
     </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secundary ml-2" id="cadastrar" onclick="cadastrar()" type="submit">Cadastrar-se como <span></span></button>
</div>
```

[image: Formulário printado]

Eu precisava pegar o dado de marcação dos termos e condições desse formulário para eu validar também... MAs não estou conseguindo...

o código que estou usando no Js é:

```
let termosCondicoes = document.querySelector('form#formCadastro #accept-term')
```

Comment: Só uma dúvida: por que teria que ser em Vanilla já que está usando jQuery?

Comment: Por que tb existem duas divs `<div class="valid-feedback">`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acesse a propriedade `.checked`:

```js
function checar(){
  let termosCondicoes = document.getElementById('accept-term');
  if(termosCondicoes.checked)
    alert('Li e concordo com os Termos de uso está marcado');
   else
   alert(' Li e concordo com os Termos de uso não está marcado');
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check form-group" id="areaTermosCondicoes">
     <input type="checkbox" id="accept-term" class="form-check-input">
     <label for="accept-term" class="form-check-label">Li e concordo com os <a href="#">Termos de uso</a></label>
     <div class="invalid-feedback">
          <span class="alert-message"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="valid-feedback">
          <span class="alert-message"></span>
     </div>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secundary ml-2" id="cadastrar" onclick="checar()" type="submit">Checar <span></span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: show... chegando em casa eu testo... vlw mesmo!